# C# Teams WebHook non async

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I have a form that runs code and sends messages based on starting, stopping and exit or exception to a Teams WebHook.

I can get everything working except the application exit or form closed event handlers, my httpClient always wants to convert the methods to async tasks and thus they don't work if I do that. When I exit, the message is not sent on form closed or application exit.

How can I solve that? Can I use non async instead to send the message to the Teams WebHook?

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            if (finished == "finished")
            {
                //Teams Bot Exit
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "myURLhere"))
                    {
                        request.Content = new StringContent("{'text':'" + CusMovexNum + " Database Cleanup Tool exited.'}");
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); //doesn't like this
                    }
                }
                

            }
            if (finished == "")
            {
                //Teams Bot Exit
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "myURLhere"))
                    {
                        request.Content = new StringContent("{'text':'" + CusMovexNum + " Database Cleanup tool exited before finishing!'}");
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); //doesn't like this
                    }
                }

                

            }
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

Comment: Async is the modern, preferred way of doing anything that involves I/O.  I'm guessing you haven't used async/await and are somehow forcing async methods to be async, and it's failing.  How about posting some code?

Comment: I added the form closed method from the event handler and it wants to convert the method to async.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need (or in this case don't *want*) the operations to run asynchronously, simply use the synchronous versions instead. This means that, instead of:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

you'd use:

```
var response = httpClient.Send(request);
```

It means the form close will 'hang' for a bit (as long as the web call takes to complete), but at least it will complete, which is what you're wanting to happen.